# Enable HTML content inside a gt table R

Tags: html, r, gt

I would like to create a gt table.
My table contains some html code in a couple of columns e.g. `<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>"`

Right now when I run

`gt(table1)`

[image]

I obtain this, which is far from desirable.

```
dput(table1)
structure(list(Variable = c("GDP", "", "", "", "Private consumption", 
"", "", "", "Business investmnet", "", "", "", "Housing investment", 
"", "", "", "", "Trade", "", "", "", "", "Labour markets", "", 
"", "", "", "", "Wages", "", "", "Prices", "", "", "", "Memo items", 
"", "", "", ""), Indicator = c("Real GDP growth", "Industrial production", 
"Composite output PMI", "ESI", "Consum. expenditure", "New passenger car registrations", 
"Retail sales", "Consumer confidence", "GFCF-excl. construction", 
"Capital goods production", "PMI manu. (output of capital goods)", 
"PMI manu. (new orders of capital goods)", "GFCF - residential investment", 
"GFCF - construction", "Construction production", "Building constrcution production", 
"Building constrcution production", "Net exports - contribution to GDP growth", 
"Nominal extra-euro area exports", "Nominal extra-euro area imports", 
"Nominal extra-euro area imports", "Assessment of export order-book levels", 
"Employment growth", "Unemployment rate", "PMI composite employment", 
"ESI - empl. expectations (manufacturing)", "ESI - empl. expectations (construction)", 
"ESI - empl. expectations (services)", "Negotiated wages", "Negotiated wages (excl. one-off payments)", 
"Compensation per employee (CPE)", "HICP", "HICP x", "Dom. producer price infl. (non-food c. goods)", 
"Import price index (extra euro area), Consumer goods industry excluding food and tobacco", 
"Loans to the private sector", "PMI services business activity", 
"M3", "Forward inflation-linked swap prices (5y5y)", "Citigroup economic surprise index"
), Frequency = c("q", "m", "m", "m", "q", "m", "m", "m", "q", 
"m", "m", "m", "q", "q", "m", "m", "m", "q", "m", "m", "m", "m", 
"q", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "q", "m", "m", "m", "m", 
"m", "m", "m", "b", "b"), Units = c("% Changes", "% Changes", 
"50 = no change", "% bal", "% Changes", "% Changes", "% Changes", 
"% bal", "% Changes", "% Changes", "50 = no change", "50 = no change", 
"% Changes", "% Changes", "% Changes", "% Changes", "% Changes", 
"pps", "% Changes", "% Changes", "50 = no change", "% bal", "% Changes", 
"% Changes", "50 = no change", "% bal", "% bal", "% bal", "% per annum", 
"% per annum", "% per annum", "% per annum", "% per annum", "% per annum", 
"% per annum", "% per annum", "50 = no change", "% per annum", 
"% per annum", "% per annum"), Reference_period = c("2022Q3", 
"Sep 22", "Nov 22", "Nov 22", "2022Q3", "Oct 22", "Oct 22", "Nov 22", 
"2022Q3", "Sep 22", "Oct 22", "Oct 22", "2022Q3", "2022Q3", "Sep 22", 
"Jan 22", "Nov 22", "2022Q2", "Sep 22", "Sep 22", "Nov 22", "Nov 22", 
"2022Q3", "Oct 22", "Nov 22", "Nov 22", "Nov 22", "Nov 22", "Sep 22", 
"Sep 22", "2022Q3", "Nov 22", "Nov 22", "Oct 22", "Oct 22", "Oct 22", 
"Nov 22", "Oct 22", "Dec 22", "Dec 22"), Last_obs = c(0.32, 0.943396226415103, 
47.85, 93.7, 0.87, 1.67294099307111, -1.83406113537117, -23.92, 
7.73006178714422, 1.50801131008484, 47.37, 39.68, -0.68584269394087, 
-0.856691337279713, 0.0909918107370231, 4.15129151291514, -12.0004230219558, 
-0.75, 1.64451122685591, -1.97449043365181, 41.56, -8.56, 0.29, 
6.54, 51.79, 6.94, 7.65, 10.81, 2.76, 2.78, 1.09363968979366, 
10, 5, 9.30674264007595, 8.5148514851485, 6.48, 48.52, 5.11, 
2.34, 37.7), Change_over_previous_period = c(NA, 0.51, 0.52, 
NA, NA, 10.3875157992464, -1.31694468832308, NA, NA, 1.26, -0.12, 
-3.09, NA, NA, -1.04, 3.04228780042592, -11.2255942377121, NA, 
2.61, 5.98, 1.98, NA, NA, -1.53651383660012, -0.73, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.09, NA, NA, NA), One_y = c("<span style=\"color:red\"> &#9660;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:yellow\">&#10134;</span>", "<span style=\"color:red\"> &#9660;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:red\"> &#9660;</span>", "<span style=\"color:yellow\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:yellow\">&#10134;</span>", "<span style=\"color:red\"> &#9660;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:yellow\">&#10134;</span>", "<span style=\"color:yellow\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:yellow\">&#10134;</span>", "<span style=\"color:red\"> &#9660;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:red\"> &#9660;</span>", "<span style=\"color:yellow\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:yellow\">&#10134;</span>", "<span style=\"color:yellow\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:green\"> &#9650;</span>", "<span style=\"color:yellow\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:yellow\">&#10134;</span>", "<span style=\"color:yellow\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:red\"> &#9660;</span>", "<span style=\"color:red\"> &#9660;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:red\"> &#9660;</span>", "<span style=\"color:red\"> &#9660;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:red\"> &#9660;</span>", "<span style=\"color:red\"> &#9660;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:red\"> &#9660;</span>", "<span style=\"color:yellow\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:yellow\">&#10134;</span>", "<span style=\"color:yellow\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:green\"> &#9650;</span>", "<span style=\"color:yellow\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:green\"> &#9650;</span>", "<span style=\"color:green\"> &#9650;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:green\"> &#9650;</span>", "<span style=\"color:green\"> &#9650;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:yellow\">&#10134;</span>", "<span style=\"color:red\"> &#9660;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:red\"> &#9660;</span>", "<span style=\"color:green\"> &#9650;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:yellow\">&#10134;</span>"), Six_y = c("<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", "<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", "<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", "<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:red\"> &#9660;</span>", "<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", "<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:red\"> &#9660;</span>", "<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", "<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", "<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", "<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", "<span style=\"color:red\"> &#9660;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", "<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:red\"> &#9660;</span>", "<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", "<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", "<span style=\"color:green\"> &#9650;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:green\"> &#9650;</span>", "<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:green\"> &#9650;</span>", "<span style=\"color:green\"> &#9650;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:green\"> &#9650;</span>", "<span style=\"color:green\"> &#9650;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:green\"> &#9650;</span>", "<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>", "<span style=\"color:green\"> &#9650;</span>", 
"<span style=\"color:#FFB400\">&#10134;</span>")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-40L))
```

What should I do to enable the html code in my table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render your HTML columns you have to format them using `gt::fmt_markdown`

```
library(gt)

gt(table1) |> 
  fmt_markdown(columns = ends_with("_y"))
```

[image]